# Why do I receive "as non-null is null" error after Android Studio converts Java code into Kotlin code automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

When I copy and paste Code B (Java Code) into Android Studio 3.1.2, I choose to convert to Kotlin code automatically.

So I get the shown Code A in Kotlin, but with the following error. Why?

Why is that error occurring when Android Studio converts the Java code into Kotlin code automatically?

BTW, Code B (Java code) works well.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter state
at ui.DialogChangePassword.showDialog(DialogChangePassword.kt)
```

**Code A (Kotlin Code)**

```
class DialogChangePassword(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : DialogPreference(context, attrs) {
    private var mView: View? = null

    init {
        dialogLayoutResource = R.layout.item_custom_password_dialog
    }

    override fun onCreateDialogView(): View? {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mView = super.onCreateDialogView()
        return mView
    }


    override fun onDialogClosed(positiveResult: Boolean) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult)
    }

    override fun showDialog(state: Bundle) {
        // Call show on default first so we can
        // override the handlers
        super.showDialog(state)

        val d = dialog as AlertDialog
        d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
            if (IsInputOKAndSavePassword()) {
                d.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun IsInputOKAndSavePassword(): Boolean {

        return true
    }

}
```

**Code B (Java Code)**

```
public class DialogChangePassword extends DialogPreference {
    private View mView;

    public DialogChangePassword(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.item_custom_password_dialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mView = super.onCreateDialogView();
        return mView;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        // Call show on default first so we can
        // override the handlers
        super.showDialog(state);

        final AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (IsInputOKAndSavePassword()){
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


    private boolean IsInputOKAndSavePassword(){
        boolean result=true;

        return result;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin treats `null` as a first class citizen by distinguishing nullable types (e.g. `Bundle?`) vs non-nullable types (e.g. `Bundle`).

as you know, a `Bundle` instance can be null depending on what phase of the component's lifecycle you're currently in. for example, the first time an `Activity` instance is created, `onCreate()` is called with a null `Bundle` because there is no state to be restored. if that same `Activity` is re-created due to a configuration change, however, `onCreate()` can be called with a non-null `Bundle` instance (in which you may have stored some data to help recreate the associated screen).

given as much, the `showDialog` signature should be written in such a way that allows for the possibility that `state` could possibly be null, like so:

```
    override fun showDialog(state: Bundle?) {
        ...
    }
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! your code is great. Does it mean that sometimes the kotin code converted by Android Studio 3.1.2 automatically isn't always correct?

Comment: given this example, not to mention just how ambitious it is to generate code across languages, I'd say it's safe to assume the results should be used as more a template or guidance rather than 100% production-ready code